# Get 2 strings from a random dictionary in a .plist

Tags: iphone, arrays, random, dictionary, plist

I am new to iphone programming. I have been struggling with this problem and have tried so many different online solutions but can't get the desired result.

I want to display 2 strings from a random array or dictionary (i'm not sure what is best to use) It would show a random question with the paired answer. Here's what i have so far:

```
<dict>
<key>q2</key>
<array>
    <string>answer2</string>
    <string>question2</string>
</array>
<key>q1</key>
<array>
    <string>answer1</string>
    <string>question1</string>
</array>
```

.m:

```
        NSString *fileContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"questions" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileContents];

    NSMutableArray *array = [plistDict objectForKey:@"q1"];

    srandom(time(NULL));

    int r = arc4random() %[array count];

    NSString *arrayData1 = [array objectAtIndex:r];
    NSString *arrayData2 = [array objectAtIndex:r+1];

    label1.text = arrayData1;
    label2.text = arrayData2;
```

This shows the correct result. But obviously its only picking it out of the 'q1' array. I would like to be able to get it from any array. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you ever notice the out of bounds exceptions that should happen every second call of this method? This code is wrong in multiple ways.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am pretty new and have been following online tutorials and my book. I really want to learn about this. If you could explain what you mean? or point me towards a useful link i would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How could this code "show the correct result"? It should crash every second (with the test data you provided) call because of an out of bounds exception caused by this code:

```
                                                    // assume array has 10 objects
int r = arc4random() %[array count];                // r = 9 

NSString *arrayData1 = [array objectAtIndex:r];     // index 9, everything ok
NSString *arrayData2 = [array objectAtIndex:r+1];   // index 9 + 1 = 10. exception
```

---

---

If I were you I would radically change the code and the structure of the data. It makes much more sense to use a NSArray for your question and a NSDictionary for each individual question.
If the keys in a dictionary are named q1, q2, q3, q4, and so on there is no reason to use a NSDictionary.

Then you could use something like this, which is much easier to understand and much cleaner.

```
NSString *pathToQuestions = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *questions = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToQuestions] autorelease];

int questionIndex = arc4random() %[questions count];

NSDictionary *question = [questions objectAtIndex:questionIndex];
NSString *answerStr = [question objectForKey:@"answer"];
NSString *questionStr = [question objectForKey:@"question"];
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong. Your code selects a random dictionary and gets 2 string values that are names answer an question. Because I just tried this and it didn't work I changed my .plist structure to: 'code' <dict>
 <key>dict2</key>
 <dict>
  <key>question</key>
  <string>john</string>
  <key>answer</key>
  <string>smith</string>
 </dict>
 <key>dict1</key>
 <dict>
  <key>question</key>
  <string>dave</string>
  <key>harold</key>
  <string>mahmood</string>
 </dict>
</dict>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `NSMutableArray *array = [plistDict objectForKey:@"q1"];` only the array from q1 will be taken. You have to obtain the array randomly by choosing the key for the dictionary randomly.

**UPDATE**

For example if u have say 7 arrays of questions named q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7. you have to choose an array randomly from this. So you can use

```
int q = arc4random() %[[plistDict allKeys] count];
NSMutableArray *randomQuestionarray = [[plistDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"q%d",q]];
```

This will give you the random array for the questions

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just can't figure out the syntax for the function you mentioned. could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: And pls check what @fluchtplunkt said. that will cause an issue

Answer (score 0):

**@7KV7** is right,you will need randomly formated key's at run time.

For andomly formated key's, you require the starting text of your key, in your case it's **q** and number of keys,

for example let's suppose you have total 50 key the your key values must be like this 
q0,q1,q2, ----- q49.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
...


NSInteger myRandomInt  = arc4random() % numberOfKeys ;
NSString myRandomKey = [[NSSting alloc]  initWithFormat:@"q%d", myRandomInt];

NSMutableArray *array = [plistDict objectForKey:myRandomKey];
```